# Wordpress database returns error 500

Tags: database, wordpress, upgrade

I have upgraded wordpress to latest version 4.2. Wordpress got updated successfully, website is visible. But when i access mywebsite.com/wp-admin It asks me to update to the newest wordpress database, I click that update button and after a while it returns error 500 Internal Server Error.

I tried to rename plugin folder/ my theme as well but to no avail.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you very much,

Comment: check `wp-config.php` on the wordpress root directory that holds the database information, This error generally occure when your wordpress not able to access database.

Comment: I double checked that. They are correct; otherwise my website wouldn't be working, by that i mean the website is still working only the administration panel that is not; showing me the update button

Comment: Thank you jogesh_pi!!! I managed to solve it check the answer. Have a good day Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an extremely tricky one! I had to enter PhpMyAdmin and update manually  the db_version in wp_options (http://prntscr.com/6yqm5l) with the version number from the latest wordpress download package (http://prntscr.com/6yqnew)

I hope this will help others who ever encounter this issue.

Thank you,

Comment: This worked for me as well. Can be done with MySQL Workbench too ;)