# WordPress Error Message on Admin Login Page: "Sorry You are Not Allowed to Access this Page"

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

When I go to my login page in WordPress and login, an error message pops up saying "Sorry You are Not Allowed to Access this Page." I tried deactivating both my plugin and current theme through FTP but that did not seem to fix the problem. I can't figure out what could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: move all plugins from plugin folder and try to login

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin ? If yes, you will need to edit wp.config.php along with other files check here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/other_notes/

if you are using total cache or any other alternative cache check their notes as well.

Comment: @HasiburRahaman You mean move them to another folder?

Comment: take a backup all plugins and delete all plugins, and try to run,

Comment: @HasiburRahaman I renamed the plugins folder - does that not work the same way?

Comment: when this problem come,

Comment: put this `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in wp-config.php It could give you a hint where the problem is located

Comment: @HasiburRahaman it just happened this morning. The only thing I did was add a few bookings through this plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/booking/), removed a user and added a new one, and made a few text edits using Advanced Custom Fields. We recently added an SSL last week. Could that be causing it?

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder thanks just tried that. Here what I'm getting: 

Strict Standards: Declaration of c2c_ConfigureSMTP::options_page_description() should be compatible with C2C_Plugin_023::options_page_description($localized_heading_text = '') in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/configure-smtp/configure-smtp.php on line 47

Notice: bbp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 2.3.) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3996

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder Error continued...Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘menus’ - assumed '‘menus’' in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/tomp-venues-theme/functions.php on line 80

Notice: Constant FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined in /var/www/html/wp-config.php on line 93

Comment: @bhood go to wp-content/themes/ and rename tomp-venues-theme to anything

Comment: is there any IP blocking plugins, if Yes install "tunnelbear" from Chrome Web Store any try to access from other location. or Try to find is there any cache folder, if you find any cache folder , delete this cache and try to access, if this also not remove your current theme and set it default and check.

Comment: @bhood Also... just in case rename your plugins folder to plugins.old and create an empty folder and name it plugins

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder just renamed it my theme and it removed that "menus" error message. Still getting the same error message though about not being able to access the page

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder ok just did that and it removed all the error messages except the one regarding the FORCE_SSL

Comment: @bhood also rename your .htaccess to htaccess.bak. And if you still see nothing then it's 100% wp roles check this post and apply option 2: https://www.codefetti.com/fix-wordpress-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page/

Comment: @MrJackMcfreder just tried renaming .htaccess and that didn't seem to do anything. I'll give the that post's option 2 a try

Comment: @bhood btw if you have recently updated your wordpress to a new version. check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896125/wordpress-database-returns-error-500

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
My Wordpress(WP) service was behind a proxy where SSL termination take place. At first I had to make sure `.htaccess` file is valid for my scenario. I followed this [Wordpress support documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) to verify that.
Then, I had to enable SSL for Wordpress administration (in `wp-config.php`),

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

And I had to configure WP to recognise HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO headers

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

PS: I would add these changes on the top of the `wp-config.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database prefix hasn't changed. The default is "wp_" but changing this to anything else (either in your wp-config.php) or by manually editing the database table names will break the permissions checking.

The fix is to edit `wp_options` and `wp_usermeta` (or whatever the new names are) and look for any `option_name` or `meta_key` with the value of `wp_%` and change it to use the new table prefix.

These queries should work (backup your database first)

**For options table:**

SELECT:

```
select * from newprefix_options where option_name like "wp_%"`)
```

UPDATE:

```
update newprefix_options set option_name = replace(option_name, "wp_", "newprefix_")
```

**And for usermeta**

SELECT:

```
select * from newprefix_usermeta where meta_key like "wp_%"
```

UPDATE:

```
update newprefix_usermeta set meta_key = replace(meta_key, "wp_", "newprefix_")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case my database table prefix was initially different than 'wp_' and probably after some plug-in auto update I got the specified error.

I had to rename all my tables so that they all have the default 'wp_' prefix.